# Open an HTTP connection in Rails like Java?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, json, gson, minecraft

I need to send some POST data in the form of `JSON` to a site, then begin to read it's response. I've done it here in Java:([see docs](http://pastebin.com/rBwtXJ5q))

This returns some `JSON` content:

```
{"profiles":[{"id":"069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5","name":"Notch"}],"size":1}
```

How can I open a connection like shown in my Java example in Rails? It's necessary that I am able to set the headers and what not.

Comment: There are a bunch of Ruby libraries that make this easy.  Take a look at Faraday for example: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I doubted myself. I got it, and it was pretty easy!
Here's my finished working version in Rails:

```
@toSend = {
    "name" => "Notch",
    "agent" => "MINECRAFT"
}.to_json

uri = URI.parse("https://api.mojang.com/profiles/page/1")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
req['foo'] = 'bar'
req.body = "[ #{@toSend} ]"
res = https.request(req)
@debug=  "Response #{res.code} #{res.message}: #{res.body}"
```

Libraries:
URI, HTTP, and HTTPS